First level factor does not appear in the summary table when using GLHT in R
In R, I am using the glht() function from the multcomp package to perform multiple comparisons after an anova. When I print the summary(), the first_level_factor does not appear in the output of glht().  My code is below.
summary(glht(aov(response ~ factor(block) + factor(treatment), data = my_data)))

In my data, treatment has 7 levels (ordered).  I do not see the first level factor in the summary.  I tried
summary(glht(aov(response ~ factor(block) + factor(treatment)-1, data = my_data)))

but this did not help. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Never heard of the reference category?
